# How to remove commons-beanutils-core from a project

Tags: maven, apache-commons

**Background**

`commons-beanutils-core` version 1.8.0 has some security issues that I am trying to avoid.
So, I am using `commons-beanutils` 1.9.4

**Problem**

I cannot seem to prevent other libraries from importing `commons-beanutils-core` version 1.8.0. Nowhere in my pom file do I include it. I am assuming some other dependency implicitly includes it. And, since `commons-beanutils-core` no longer is supported and they have moved to just using `commons-beanutils` for all newer versions, when I explicitly write:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

It does not remove the implicit references to `commons-beanutils-core`.

**Question**

How do I make the other packages not download `commons-beanutils-core` version 1.8.0?

**Notes:**

There have been other packages that were downloaded as dependencies that I did not explicitly include in my pom.xml. A scan show that some of these packages were security risks. So, my solution was to just explicitly include a higher version of the package that was previously included implicitly. And that removed the old version of the package. But that solution does not work here since `commons-beanutils-core` is no longer used in the newest version.

**Update 1**

I have learned that including the following code will make the pom.xml think that 1.8.0 will be provided, and in a sense it will since I will include 1.9.4. But I am unsure if the code will use the 1.9.4 if it thinks it should look for 1.8.0. This code enables me to remove 1.8.0 but I don't know if my deception here will cause problems down the line.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using provided scope can have side effects on runtime. Provided scope dependencies are used in compilation but not packaged so if the `commons-beanutils-core` has a method which is not present in `commons-beanutils` you will get `NoSuchMethodException`.

Better solution will be use [`mvn dependency:tree`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) to find which dependencies had dependency on `commons-beanutils-core` and

1. Either update the dependency to a version which uses `1.9.4` version of `commons-beanutils`.
2. Or use [`exclusion`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#dependency-exclusions) to exclude `commons-beanutils-core` from the dependencies using `commons-beanutils-core` as a dependency.

If you can use method 1 it's better if you cannot find a dependency which uses the latest version, then use method 2.